# Grouping array values by similar

Tags: php, arrays

i'm making a grocerylist system that takes into account amount of recipies you throw at it.
based on that, it combines values and outputs a grocerylist for you.

i'm looping a mysql query and create arrays like this:

```
foreach sql loop{
  $ingredients = array(
    "id"=>array($id),
    "name"=>array($name),
    "amount"=>array($amount),
    "unit"=>array($unit)
  );
    foreach ($ingredienser as $key => $value) {
      foreach ($value as $index => $v) {
        echo $key."=";
        echo $v;
        echo "<br><hr>";
      }
    }
 }
```

That whole ordeal outputs a list like this if i throw 1 recipe at it:

```
id=150
name=Cherrytomater
amount=300
unit=Gram
id=151
name=Kyllingfilet
amount=4
unit=Stykk
```

if i throw 2 recipies it throws the next recipe under it.

However, i need it to do a certain set of things.

1. merge values if the name is similar
2. ignore the above merge if unit is different (its a shopping list after all)
3. output a combined list of ingredients based on the recipies and amount of recipies i throw at it.

To further explain; the sql equivalent of what im trying to achieve is :

```
$dupe = "2" //amount of similar recipies
SELECT i.id, i.ingred, r.enhet, r.id, SUM(r.mengde * $dupe) total, r.enhet FROM oppskriftingred r left join ingrediens i on i.id = r.ingrediens WHERE r.oppskriftid IN $vars2 GROUP BY i.ingred, r.enhet ORDER BY i.ingred
```

However, the sql approach wont work as the SUM doesn't differentiate between  different recipies.. if $ dupe is 4 for one recipe and 2 for another, its 4 for both.

So how can i do this in php with arrays? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your "this is what I need list" has one problematic point:
1. merge value if the name is SIMILAR

The rest is quite simple. You have an array of ingerdients $ingredients. You need to loop through this and compare every entry to a result array, to figure out if your points 2 and 1 match it to a existing or new entry. I would give the new array a key, that makes matching easy. Let's say the unit and the name as a string: 'Gram-Cherrytomater'

```
$result = array();
foreach ($ingerdients as $item) {
    $newKey = $item['unit'].'-'.$item['name'];
    if (isset($result[$newKey]) {
        // add amount to existing item
        $result[$newKey]['amount'] += $item['amount'];
    } else {
         // add new item
          $result[$newKey] = $item;
    }
}
// now loop trough the result and display whatever you want
```

The problem is with the SIMILAR thing. I do not know, how you want to compare to strings that are similar. You should do this when getting the $newKey. Do something with $item['name'] to make it "similar".

You could use some php function like similar_text(), levenshtein() or soundex(). I do not know how good this works for your language (Danish?).

Comment: Hey! thanks for replying :)
I'm not very good with arrays, so im trying my best to understand and learn. If i understand correctly, matching the names is problematic because it is not an integer? i can surely add some identifying integer to it =)

If you were faced with this scenario, what option would you go for?
and you are close! norwegian =)

Comment: Matching "similar" is problematic, because what is similar? You could try to use one of the given php functions to create the key. But not shure how that works in your language. Or if you habe a complete list of all possible ingredients, match them with a number (give the same number to similar ingredients). And get familiar with arrays. They are a very basic thing in php and quite powerful.

Comment: its called from a list of ingredients with both unique id and name. 
so if the ingredientname occurs twice it would merge the two. kind of like mysql's group by. 
trying with arrays, but so far it's not going too good. im struggling with articulating the logic behind the merge.